# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So im making a command to kick people(ofcourse) and theres a part where i wanna let people know if they dont have permision or the bot dosent have permision to kick the specified person, but then i came across this error whenever I tried to run the code

> const mentionedRank = mentionedMember.roles.highest.position;
> ^
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')

My whole code for that command is:

```
    if (isCommand === 'kick') {
        const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();
        const mentionedRank = mentionedMember.roles.highest.position;
        const memberRank = message.member.roles.highest.position;
        const botRank = message.guild.me.roles.highest.position;
        var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ')
        if(!reason) {
             reason = 'no defined reason'
        }

        if(!message.member.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS'))
            embed = embed
            .setDescription('You do not have the permission to kick a user!')
            .setColor("BLUE")
            message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
        if(!message.guild.me.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS'))
            embed = embed
            .setDescription('I do not have the permission to kick a user')
            .setColor("BLUE")
            message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
        if(memberRank <= mentionedRank){
            embed = embed
            .setDescription('You cannot kick that user as they have a equal/higher rank as you')
            .setColor("BLUE")
            message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
        }
        if(botRank <= mentionedRank){
            embed = embed
            .setDescription('I cannot kick that user as they have a equal/higher rank than me')
            .setColor("BLUE")
            message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
        }
        
        if(!args[0]){
            embed = embed
            .setDescription('Please specify the user that you want to kick!')
            .setColor("BLUE")
            message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
        }
        if(member){
        member.kick();
        let guildname = client.guilds.fetch()
        embed = embed
        .setTitle(`${mentionedMember} kicked!`)
        .setDescription(`${mentionedMember} was kicked from the server for ${reason}.`)
        .setColor("BLUE")
        message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
    } else{
        embed = embed
        .setDescription(`"${args[0]}" was not found`)
        .setColor("BLUE")
        message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you `mentionedMember` is `undefined`. That means in the second line of code you showed, `message.mentions.members.first()` is returning `undefined`.

Comment: yeah, but why? can you please explain? thanks

Comment: You'd need to show more code. I can't infer the type of `message` in `message.mentions.members.first()`, and cannot know what `metions` and `members` are. Please refer to the documentation of the library on the types of these variables and how they handle edge cases (e.g. what if no users were mentioned?)

Comment: Can you log `message` and show us it?

Comment: What did it return @Leuqas ?

Comment: hey im sorry for the late reply, but heres "message", 
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
//code
}